# set maximum character input size of react CreatableSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using creatable select to allow the user to input a new option that is not in the dropdown list. But after looking I cannot seem to see a way of setting the maximum input to 50 characters for input before creating in the creatable select.

I have looked at taking the new entry and if over 50 characters deleting it however this seems a long way round and would like to use something that is shorter on the actual input when the user selects create.

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

const cars = [
  { label: "audi", value: 1 },
  { label: "bmw", value: 2 },
  { label: "ford", value: 3 },
  { label: "VW", value: 4 },
];

const selectOption = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="container">
      <CreatableSelect
         options={cars} 
         placeholder={"check and enter new car name here"}
         isClearable
         onChange={(opt, meta) => console.log(opt, meta)}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default selectOption
```

I am hoping there is a max input option i just dont know. Thank you for taking the time to look at this/help, very much appreciated.

Comment: do you want the option to be anyway created when user enters more than 50 characters (limiting the name to 50 characters), or not allow the user to create an option when they enter more than 50 characters?

Comment: I want it so the user cannot create a new entry that is more than 50 characters. if they try it will not allow them to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put you can use the `<CreatableSelect/>` s `onCreateOption` prop. You will have to maintain your `options` and `value` in component state. Then put your control logic inside `handleCreateOption` function ( for `onCreateOption` prop ). Your `handleCreateOption` will be something like this. ( look at codesandbox for full code )

```
handleCreateOption = inputValues => {
   if (inputValue.length < 50) {
    const newOption = createOption(inputValue);
    this.setState({
      options: [...options, newOption],
      value: newOption
    });
   }
}
```

codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-codesandboxer-example-cjbgu

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to be able to type more than the limit, you can add maxLength attribute to the input.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const myRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
myRef.current.inputRef.style.minWidth = 'max-content';
myRef.current.inputRef.placeholder = placeholderText;
myRef.current.inputRef.maxLength = 20;
}, []);

<CreatableSelect
    ref={myRef}
    {...props}
    options={options}
    value={value}
    name={name}
    onChange={handleChange}
    placeholder={''}
    classNamePrefix="multi-select-custom"
    isMulti={isMulti}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar answer, and then I realized it is possible to use props components

```
         components={
           Input: (props) => {
             return (
               <components.Input {...props} maxLength={50}>
                 {props.children}
               </components.Input>
             );
           },
         }
```

code full here:

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

const cars = [
  { label: "audi", value: 1 },
  { label: "bmw", value: 2 },
  { label: "ford", value: 3 },
  { label: "VW", value: 4 },
];

const selectOption = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="container">
      <CreatableSelect
         options={cars} 
         placeholder={"check and enter new car name here"}
         isClearable
         onChange={(opt, meta) => console.log(opt, meta)}
         components={
           Input: (props) => {
             return (
               <components.Input {...props} maxLength={50}>
                 {props.children}
               </components.Input>
             );
           },
         }
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default selectOption
```